# What are some intuitions that support calling the Maybe constructor in Haskell "Just"?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, option-type

The intuition of an optional type like `Maybe Int` is that either there is **no** Int (thus, there's `Nothing` there) or that there is **some** Int; there is something there.

It makes sense to me that we call the type constructor for the "negative" case `Nothing`, since it means exactly that -- that there's no `Int` there. But why use the word **Just** in the case where the emphasis is on something **actually being there**?

To me, the word "Just" carries the connotation that the thing it's describing is **less** than the alternative; the opposite of something actually being there; for example,

> A: Are you doing anything tonight?
>
> B: No; I'm **just** gonna stay in and watch TV.
>
> A: Did you investigate the creepy ghost sounds around your house?
>
> B: yeah, turns out it was actually **just** an owl.

Clearly I'm lacking whatever intuition this naming choice was based on. What is it? Because to me, the word *Just* means the opposite of how it's used in the `Maybe` type.

Comment: "Just" can mean "exactly or precisely" ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/just?s=t)). For example, "That is just what the doctor ordered."

Comment: Maybe because "Definitely" (which would be the perfect word for this) is a lot longer than "Just"?

Comment: @Libby Standard ML and OCaml use the word "some", which I think carries the right meaning

Comment: Q: What is the value of X? A: "Nothing" / "Just 12". Would you answer "None" / "Some 12"? Anyway, I don't think this question can be answered objectively. Further, I believe it's quite common to have a preference for the first notation we met, since we consider that familiar and anything else feels alien.

Comment: @chi For what it’s worth, I learned Haskell before I used any other language with optionals, and I found `Just` a fairly curious name. I agree this question isn’t answerable without knowing what the person who named it was thinking, though.

Comment: FWIW, I would have named it `Something`. Then `Maybe x` is either `Something` or `Nothing`...